# Is db_query thread safe?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am working with MySQL in C++. I had an issue before with `mysql_query()` not being thread safe (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html.) Is `db_query()` any different or do the rules in the first bullet point from the doc I linked to apply to `db_query()` too? I assume they operate the same, but I want to make sure it isn't slightly different and end up unlocking my mutex too quickly or leave it locked longer than necessary. Sorry I couldn't find any documentation specifically on this issue for `db_query()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I didn't realize that this `db_query()` was imported from another file. I'm still learning the code base :/ No wonder I couldn't find any documentation on it! Sorry to whomever's time I wasted.

...And it isn't thread safe. It is just a wrapper for `mysql_query()` doh XD